# Could `if-then-else` (always) be replaced by a function call?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

This question is out of curiousity about how PLs work, more than anything else. (It actually came to me while looking at SML which differs from Haskell in that the former uses call-by-value - but my question is about Haskell.)

Haskell (as I understand) has "call-by-need" semantics. 
Does this imply that if I define a function as follows:

```
cond True thenExp elseExp = thenExp 
cond _ thenExp elseExp = elseExp
```

that this will always behave exactly like an if-then-else expression?
Or, in another sense, can if-then-else be regarded as syntactic sugar for something that could've been defined as a function?

---

**Edit:**

Just to contrast the behaviour of Haskell with Standard ML, define (in SML)

`cond p t f = if p then t else f;`

and then the factorial function

`fun factc n = cond (n=0) 1 (n * factc (n-1));`

evaluating factc 1 (say) never finishes, because the recursion in the last argument of `cond` never terminates.

However, defining

`fun fact n = if n=0 then 1 else fact (n-1);`

works as we expect because the then branch is only evaluated as needed.

Maybe there are clever ways to defer argument evaluation in SML (don't know as I'm not that familiar with it yet) but the point is that in a call-by-value type language, if-then-else often behaves differently. 
My question was whether this (call-by-need vs call-by-value) was the principle reason behind this difference (and the consensus seems to be "yes").

Comment: your code should work perfectly

Comment: I would also use `False` here, since it could be possible that the first expression is `undefined`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did wonder if the catch-all could be anything other than `False`, didn't think of `undefined` though as I'm not that familiar with it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The function is already strict in the first argument because of the pattern match with. `True`. So using `_` vs. `False` won't make a difference.

Comment: @sepp2k: yeah indeed, since the pattern guard `True <- undefined` will error, but nevertheless it is better to be explicit over implicit.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in Haskell, as in many (FP) languages with algebraic data types, the `if` conditional is not as important as `case of` (and other related pattern matching constructs). Often, good Haskell code uses booleans much less frequently. In Haskell we would never have Java's `Scanner.hasNext()` and `next()`, the latter throwing when the first returns false. We would simply have `next :: .. -> Maybe Stuff` (or some monadic variant), where booleans disappeared in favor of better types.

Comment: @chi: Although that is more a matter of API design than functional programming or algebraic data types. This particular Java API you mention is widely considered broken even amongst OO and Java programmers. (The same is true for the equivalent `TryParse` idiom in .NET.)

Comment: For the 

"Maybe there are clever ways to defer argument evaluation in SML" 

part: the simple way is just to make `t` and `f` parameters functions `unit -> 'a`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I did consider something like that.. specifically, I was thinking there might be an ML equivalent of "autoclosures" in Swift, but I don't know if they have a clean syntax in ML. But anyway, syntax is a secondary issue, so yeah...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the [*Haskell Wikipedia on `if-then-else`*](https://wiki.haskell.org/If-then-else) says:

> For processing conditions, the `if-then-else` **syntax was defined in Haskell98**. However it could be simply replaced by the function `if'`
> with
>
> ```
> if' :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
> if' True  x _ = x
> if' False _ y = y
> ```

So if we use the above `if'` function, and we *need to evaluate it* (since Haskell is lazy, we do not necessary need to evaluate an `if`-`then`-`else` expression at all), Haskell will first evaluate the first operand to decide if it is `True` or `False`. In case it is `True`, it will return the first expression, if it is `False` it will return the second expression. Note that this does *not* per se means that we (fully) evaluate these expressions. Only when we need the result, we will evaluate the expressions.

But in case the condition is `True`, there is no reason at all to ever evaluate the second expression, since we ignore it.

In case we share an expression over multiple parts of the expression tree, it is of course possible that another call will (partially) evaluate the other expression.

`ghci` even has an option to override the `if <expr> then <expr> else <expr>` syntax: the [**`-XRebindable`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) flag. It will, besides other things also:

> Conditionals (e.g. `if e1 then e2 else e3`) means `ifThenElse e1 e2 e3`. However case expressions are unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a lazy language will evaluate an expression only when it needs to. Therefore it is no problem to convert the then/else parts of the expression into function arguments.

This is unlike strict languages like Idris or OCaml, where arguments for a function call are evaluated before the called function is executed.

Comment: Although you can always trivially introduce laziness by wrapping the arguments in lambdas (and you can hide this wrapping in a language with macros). Smalltalk, for example, implements conditionals in a manner which is essentially identical to the Church encoding of Booleans in lambda-calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can regard `if/then/else` as syntactic sugar. In fact, a programming language doesn't even need Boolean primitives, so you can also consider `True` and `False` as syntactic sugar.

The [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) defines Boolean values as a set of functions that take two arguments:

```
true = λt.λf.t
false = λt.λf.f
```

Both functions are functions that takes two values, `t` for *true*, and `f` for *false*. The function `true` always returns the `t` value, whereas the function `false` always returns the `f` value.

In Haskell, you can define similar functions like this:

```
true  = \t f -> t
false = \t f -> f
```

You could then write your `cond` function like:

```
cond = \b t f -> b t f
```

Examples:

```
Prelude> cond true "foo" "bar"
"foo"
Prelude> cond false "foo" "bar"
"bar"
```

Read more in Travis Whitaker's article [Scrap Your Constructors: Church Encoding Algebraic Types](http://programmable.computer/posts/church_encoding.html).

Comment: I am (passingly) familiar with the lambda calculus encoding of booleans, but I think the issue I'm talking about has to do with normal order vs. applicative order evaluation... unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: Also, whether `if-then-else` *could* be syntactic sugar is a different question than *is* it syntactic sugar (as it is in Haskell, for a `case` expression).