# Defines a function that lets you see if the integer m is a multiple of n

Tags: string, if-statement, haskell, types

I cannot have a correct use of if-sentences and I get the error "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)".

I've tried to use different if-sentences, but my experience is in Imperative Language, so I really don't know how to use properly the if-sentences in Haskell

> ```
> multiple m n = mod m n
> if mod m n /= 0 then "not multiple"
> ```

OR

> ```
> multiple m n = mod m n
> if mod m n = 0
> then putStrLn "multiple"
> ```

OR

> ```
> if multiple m n = 0 then "multiple m n" = "multiple"
> ```

And another amount of things

I expected to get an answer like "Multiple" or "Not Multiple".

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close. You can see an `if … then … else …` as a ternary operator in imperative languages. There is nothing special about `if … then … else …`, it can be seen as syntactical sugar for an expression `if' … … …`, and it has the same laziness rules as any other function. So it is similar to `… ? … : …` in Java, C#, etc.

You thus can define this as:

```
multiple :: Integral a => a -> a -> String
multiple m n = if mod m n /= 0 then "not multiple" else "multiple"
```

Comment: Not sure how lazy evaluation is relevant here. Particularly for if/then/else, Haskell's evaluation strategy is very similar to an imperative language's.

Comment: @amalloy: the `if ... then ... else ...` block itself is not eagerly evaluated. `foo = if ... then ... else ...` will not evaluate the condition, unless it is forced to evaluate `foo`.

Comment: Sure, but so what? That's true of any expression. When telling someone how to implement `fib n = ...` we don't usually preface it by saying "by the way, the body will only be evaluated if the result of `fib n` is needed". In this context it sounds like you are giving advice about some special consideration that must be made for if/then/else expressions, but I know of none such.

Comment: @amalloy: indeed, although in the past I've seen some questions where the OP thinks that `if ... then ... else` is not a function (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355417/could-if-then-else-always-be-replaced-by-a-function-call), but something "special" (just like `do` notation is often seen, as something "non-functional").

Comment: But it *is* something special and not a function; it's a separate syntactic construct equivalent to `case ... of True -> ...; False -> ...`.